# getting into infinite loop when using a while loop

Tags: python, while-loop, infinite-loop

I am using this code to use a dataframe lookup for every single record in the first dataframe.

```
for i in range(len(a1)):
    title_derived = []
    k = 100000
    print(i)
    for j in range(len(b1)):
        print(j)
        while j < (k + 6):
            #print(b1.iloc[i][10], a1.iloc[j][3])
            if b1.iloc[j][10] == a1.iloc[i][3]:
                print(j,k)
                print('1st if ' + str(j))
                print (b1.iloc[j][1], a1.iloc[i][11], b1.iloc[j][5])
                if (((pd.to_datetime(b1.iloc[j][1]) <= pd.to_datetime(a1.iloc[i][11]) <= pd.to_datetime(b1.iloc[j][5]))) or ((pd.to_datetime(b1.iloc[j][1]) <= pd.to_datetime(a1.iloc[i][8]) <= pd.to_datetime(b1.iloc[j][5])))) :
                    print('2nd if' + str(j))
                    title_derived.append(b1.iloc[j][15])
                    print('inserted ' + b1.iloc[j][15] + ' in ' + str(i) + ' th record ')
                a1.iat[i,65] = title_derived
```

It prints,
0
0

and then goes into a an infinite loop.

Comment: Where do you increment ``j``?

Comment: Why would you expect it to do otherwise? j is the for loop variable, it is not incremented inside the while

Comment: assign `l=j` and use `l` in while loop `while l<(k+6)` and also check for increment of `l`

Answer (score 0):

> May be it is because you are length of "b1" in lesser than value of "k + 6". And in that case you will never get out of while loop and in the last it will throw and error.
>   In this case you should first check the least possible length of "b1" and then decide your wile condition.